# Are their any custom twitter bootstrapped implementations of swagger-ui available?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, swagger, swagger-ui

I need some custom Swagger-UI implementations using twitter bootstrap or some other responsive frameworks. Need to test my API's using such an UI on my mobile device but swagger-ui does not scale well to mobile devices.
Any other UI using Swagger Specifications will also work.

Answer (score 2):

[jensoleg](https://github.com/jensoleg) created a swagger-ui that uses Twitter Bootstrap.

His fork can be found here: https://github.com/jensoleg/swagger-ui

Answer (score 0):

In the **SwaggerConfig** file, you could refer to the [bootstrap css file](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/download/v3.3.4/bootstrap-3.3.4-dist.zip):
c.InjectStylesheet(Assembly_Name, "bootstrap.min.css")

then edit in the index.html of the swagger to include any class exists in the bootstrap css.

I hope this might help.

Comment: You're assuming that the OP is using Swashbuckle, with is a .NET library to *generate* Swagger docs to be used with Swagger-UI. Swagger-UI, in and of itself, is platform independent.